# Producing and Consuming Avro messages from Kafka without Confluent components

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to find an example where I can produce and subscribe avro messages from kafka.

At this point of time, I want to use a "vanilla" kafka deployment without any confluent add-ons.

is this possible? All examples I found so far very quickly start using confluent specific tools for avro messages.

I am sure that there should be a way by which I can publish and consume avro messages on just kafka platform with any 'distribution specific' no addons.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question, there isn't any built in way to generate and load avro messages in Kafka.  Basically, you would use an avro client like fastavro to serialize to the avro format immediately before producing to Kafka and load it immediately after consumption from a topic.

Comment: So like wrap avro serialization/deserialization logic in a custom serializer?

Comment: Um... More or less, serialize it to the avro format before producing to the topic.  Depending on the client you are using, there may be shortcuts to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you can do that without any Confluent tooling.  But you have to do additional work on your side (e.g. in your application code) -- which was the original motivation of providing Avro-related tooling such as the ones from Confluent that you mentioned.

One option is to manually serialize/deserialize the payload of your Kafka messages (e.g. from `YourJavaPojo` to `byte[]`) by using the Apache Avro [Java API](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html) directly. (I suppose that you implied Java as the programming language of choice.)  How would this look like?  Here's an example.

- First, you would manually serialize the data payload in your application that writes data to Kafka.  Here, you could use the Avro serialization API for the encoding the payload (from Java pojo to `byte[]`), and then use Kafka's Java producer client for the writing encoded payload to a Kafka topic.
- Then, downstream in your data pipeline, you would deserialize in another application that reads data from Kafka.  Here, you could use Kafka's Java consumer client for the reading the (encoded) data from the same Kafka topic, and use the Avro deserialization API for the decoding the payload back again (from `byte[]` to Java pojo).

You can also use the Avro API directly, of course, when working with stream processing tools like Kafka Streams (will be included in upcoming Apache Kafka 0.10) or Apache Storm.

Lastly, you also have the option to use some utility libraries (whether from Confluent or elsewhere) so that you don't have to use the Apache Avro API directly.  For what it's worth, I have published some slightly more complex examples at [kafka-storm-starter](https://github.com/miguno/kafka-storm-starter), e.g. as demonstrated by [AvroDecoderBolt.scala](https://github.com/miguno/kafka-storm-starter/blob/develop/src/main/scala/com/miguno/kafkastorm/storm/bolts/AvroDecoderBolt.scala).  Here, the Avro serialization/deserialization is done by using the Scala library [Twitter Bijection](https://github.com/twitter/bijection).  Here's an example snippet of `AvroDecoderBolt.scala` to give you the general idea:

```
  // This tells Bijection how to automagically deserialize a Java type `T`,
  // given a byte array `byte[]`.
  implicit private val specificAvroBinaryInjection: Injection[T, Array[Byte]] =
SpecificAvroCodecs.toBinary[T]

  // Let's put Bijection to use.
  private def decodeAndEmit(bytes: Array[Byte], collector: BasicOutputCollector) {
    require(bytes != null, "bytes must not be null")
    val decodeTry = Injection.invert(bytes)  // <-- deserialization, using Twitter Bijection, happens here
    decodeTry match {
      case Success(pojo) =>
        log.debug("Binary data decoded into pojo: " + pojo)
        collector.emit(new Values(pojo)) // <-- Here we are telling Storm to send the decoded payload to downstream consumers
        ()
      case Failure(e) => log.error("Could not decode binary data: " + Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(e))
    }
  }
```

So yes, you can of course opt to not use any additional libraries such as Confluent's Avro serializers/deserializers (currently made available as part of [confluentinc/schema-registry](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry)) or [Twitter's Bijection](https://github.com/twitter/bijection).  Whether that's worth the additional effort is up to you to decide.